# Python Loop with sinus and two variables

Tags: python

I would like to set up a loop with two variables from two arrays. Inputs are geographical coordinates and I want to calculate their distance to a certain point location (X0, Y0).

So far, I have:

```
x = open('Long.txt','r').read().splitlines()
y = open('Lat.txt','r').read().splitlines()

### Convert to array 
x_array = np.array(x)
y_array = np.array(y)

### Define location of origin
Y0 = -21
X0 = 170

sin0=sin(Y0)
cos0=cos(Y0)

### Calculate distance for each geographical coordinate pair (x_array,y_array)

for i, j in zip(x_array, y_array):
    distance = arccos(sin0*sin(j)+cos0*cos(j)*cos(X0-i))
    print distance
```

However, I get the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'sin' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

If someone could please help me with this one, that would be great! Thank you so much in advance!

Isi

Comment: Could you post the values of `x_array` and `y_array`?

Comment: You should show the relevant import statements, because while it may be clear from the error message, from the code itself, it is not possible to tell whether `sin` refers to `math.sin` or `numpy.sin`.

Comment: You should also post the full traceback, because there are multiple calls to `sin`, so strictly, it is not possible to determine at which point the `TypeError` is raised (presumably not in the first call, but strictly speaking, this can't be certain).

Comment: Please use Python 3. Python 2 is abandoned, and should not be used for any new code.

Answer (score 0):

You never convert your input values to numbers: `x_array` and `y_array` will be NumPy arrays of strings, not arrays of numbers. You can't perform `sin` operations on arrays of strings. Convert the strings to numbers first:

```
x_array = np.array(x).astype(np.float)
```

and similar for `y_array`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate distance, something needed to do firstly:

- convert string value of x, y to float
- use math or numpy to calculate trigonometric functions, here for math.
- convert angle to radian

Example:

```
import math

x = ['12.5', '33']
y = ['33.5', '11.3']

Y0 = -21
X0 = 170

X = map(float, x)
Y = map(float, y)

sin0 = math.sin(Y0/180*math.pi)
cos0 = math.cos(Y0/180*math.pi)

for i, j in zip(X, Y):
    distance = math.acos(sin0*math.sin(j/180*math.pi)+cos0*math.cos(j/180*math.pi)*math.cos((X0-i)/180*math.pi))
    print(distance)
```

Comment: Updated as above.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't state their input needs conversion (it may already be in radions), although the 170 is a giveaway it does require a conversion to radians.

Comment: Revised from list to map for X and Y